# Multiple Images Compression to Save Space

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gif

I have over 700 gifs that I use in my iOS App. I plan on adding 700 more.

Is there anyway to have the multitude of images compressed in something like a `zip` or `tar` file and within the code unzip, exclude that one image, and then recompress them all within the app?